# Edit Model data using ModelForm: ModelForm validation error

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I am working on my first django app. I am building an app that allows the user to rate beer. I want my user to be able to edit an entry they've already created. I take them to a ModelForm, and ask for their entry. When the POST method is called, my data is invalid. Here is my model.py:

```
from django.db import models


 class Rating(models.Model):
    beer_name = models.TextField()
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    brewer = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

and forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from ratings.models import Rating


class RatingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ['beer_name', 'score', 'notes', 'brewer']
```

Here is the views.py of my edit function:

```
def edit(request, row_id):
    rating = get_object_or_404(Rating, pk=row_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RatingForm(request.POST, instance=rating)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(home)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid entry.")
    else:
        context = {'form': rating}
        form = RatingForm(instance=rating)
        return render(
            request,
            'ratings/entry_def.html',
            context
        )
```

However, every time the POST is called I get an "Invalid entry." HttpResponse, meaning my form.is_valid() is being returned False. Here is my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <h2>Edit Rating</h2>
        <form role="form" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <p>Beer Name: <textarea>{{ form.beer_name }}</textarea></p>
          <p>Score: <input type="text" name="BeerScore" value="{{ form.score }}"></p>
          <p>Notes: <textarea>{{ form.notes }}</textarea></p>
          <p>Brewer: <textarea>{{ form.brewer }}</textarea></p>
          <p><button type="submit" class="save btn btn-primary">Save</button></p>
          <p><button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

So when I press my Save button, I am getting the response. Here is my edit url in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'rating/edit/(?P<row_id>[0-9]+)/$', edit , name='rating-edit'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrapping fields in other fields which don't have `name` attributes. This is most likely causing the values to be excluded from the `request.POST` data.

Additionally, Django form fields all have a corresponding HTML widget. So there's really no need to render the HTML by hand, unless you need to.

Change your template code to:

```
<p>
    {{ form.beer_name.label }}: {{ form.beer_name }}
    {% if form.beer_name.errors %}
    <br />{{ form.beer_name.errors }}
    {% endif %}{# repeat for other fields as needed #}
</p>
<p>{{ form.score.label }}: {{ form.score }}</p>

<p>{{ form.notes.label }}: {{ form.notes }}</p>
<p>{{ form.brewer.label }}: {{ form.brewer }}</p>
<p><button type="submit" class="save btn btn-primary">Save</button></p>
<p><button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button></p>
```

If you need to change the widget, do so at the form class level:

```
class RatingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RatingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['notes'].widget = forms.Textarea()
```

This way, Django manages the attributes and binding for you.

Your view can also use some cleanup:

```
def edit(request, row_id):
    rating = get_object_or_404(Rating, pk=row_id)
    form = RatingForm(request.POST or None, instance=rating)

    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect(home)

    context = {'form': rating}
    return render(request, 'ratings/entry_def.html', context)
```

Comment: Awesome! Every time I tried to take the <textarea> html tag off, the text wouldn't be editable. It would just display the text. Thank you so much!